# Brotherhood of Steel is now my enemy, what now?

Tags: fallout-4

After I got my rank as a Knight, I was roaming in the big zeppelin untill I saw a couple molerats in a cage, i decided to shoot them, as i turned around the whole zeppelin was shooting at me. I killed their leader(maxus?) and a couple other Knights. Can i still join or work for the BoS or am I going to stay their enemy?

all the BoS quests are deleted from my Quest tab

Comment: If you killed the leader who gives you the quests why do you think you can still get him to give you quests? :)

Comment: maybe he'll spawn back :P so i got got 3 factions to choose from now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that depends on what you want to do - if you want to be enemies with the Brotherhood of Steel you can go and speak to Preston Garvey at the Sanctuary and this should allow you to continue the story with the Minutemen.

If you don't want to be enemies with the Brotherhood of Steel then load an earlier save.